# Как изменить url fetch? (github)

Tags: github

Как изменить url fetch? (github)
Я изменил название удаленного репозитория на github, и git push теперь не работает.
Проверил через git remote -v ссылки в push и fetch адресованы на старое имя.
url от push я поменял, а как для fetch заменить url? И от него ли push по-прежнему не работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Три способа

## Ручное редактирование конфигурации

`vim .git/config`, раздел `[remote "origin"]`

## Удалить remote и добавить снова

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://github.com/ваш-репо.git
```

## Переименовать

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/ваш-репо.git
```

Comment: Вообще сделал git remote remove.
И по новой:
git remote add origin.
git push -u origin master.
Ссылки fetch и push обновились. Но всё равно не работает -_-

Comment: `cat .git/config` в студию

Comment: $ cat .git/config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
[branch "master"]
[gui]
        wmstate = normal
        geometry = 893x435+26+26 175 196
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/Sturmtiger/PythonCourse1.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Comment: Забыли указать протокол HTTPS: `https://github.com/Sturmtiger/PythonCourse1.git`. Поправьте первым способом (просто добавьте в начало `https://`) или любым другим. Вообще git поддерживает несколько протоколов. Вы указали так, как будто репозиторий лежит на диске в каталоге `github.com/Sturmtiger/PythonCourse1.git` (да, диск может быть так тоже репозиторием).